# Find Next HTML Document in a Series

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination

I have a series of HTML files in the same directory named: page1.html, page2.html, page3.html, etc. I can identify the name of my current HTML document like this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var page = path.split("/").pop();
console.log( page );
```

But now I want to be able to log the next HTML file in the series. So if I am on page2.html, I want to log page3.html. How can I replace that file name, with the next numbered file in my series ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mico and @SugarOnBacon this solution works!

```js
var path = window.location.pathname;
var page = path.split("/").pop();

 console.log(page.replace(/\d+/g, parseInt(page.match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple:

`page=str.replace("page","");
a=parseInt(page);
a++; 
console.log("page"+a+".html");`

The first line raplaces the first part so it's "3.html" var. The second gets the integer out of page. What follows is an increment and an output.

That's one of the possibilities how it could be done.

Sources:

> [str.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
>
> [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Comment: thanks @SugarOnBacon. I am getting this error in the console when I add that code: Uncaught ReferenceError: str_replace is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This should do it with pure javaScript:

```
 var page = window.location.pathname;
 console.log(page.replace(/\d+/g, parseInt(page.match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1));
```

Inner regex takes page number + 1 and the outer one replaces the value with it.

Comment: This One Works! But it gives me "page21.html" instead of "page2.html" -- Is there a way to get it increment to 'page2.html' ?

Comment: you can use parseInt(1, 10) for the added number, too. maybe it is then not used like another string.. poor javaScript tries to guess it string when the 21 comes out.